# Django Cms - How to add customise menu in djangocms

Tags: html, css, django, django-cms

Hi Im new to cms I was implementing djangocms in my project
I have already have my html files im added placholders in that for making that content editable for example:

```
    {% block content %}
    {% placeholder "content" %}
    {% endblock content %}
```

I have added placeholder for all the places i needed when i come to menu i used placeholder it only changes in the current html page i need to change in all the page which have same header and footer

I Have tried

```
    {% show_menu 0 100 100 100 %}
```

But it comes default cms menus i need menu with my template style.

I have also tried

```
    {% include "header.html" %}
```

But the placeholder only coming the plugin i need to add link again and again in every page.

Is there any solution for while im adding plugin in header.html it will display on all the pages which have the same header ?

Comment: try this `{% show_menu 0 100 100 100 'header.html' %}`

Comment: Hi @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd It display only the template if i change in menu it is not reflecting in other pages it working same as {% include "header.html" %}

Comment: are you familiar with Django template language?

Comment: No @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd Hi almost come to the menu now i need only how to style the menu in cms can you help me